# React Hook Form Controller not working with Validate function

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hook-form

I'm trying to upload files using Controller in React Hook Form. Inside "rules", I have validate functions. However, it appears the validate funtions are not being called but their error messages are displayed.I've tried several solutions on this platform and on Github but none seems to be working for me.

Here is the input component:

```
 <Controller
            control={control}
            name={"photograph"}
            rules={{
              required: "Photograph is required!",
              validate: {
                fileSize: (file) =>
                  file[0]?.size < 1000100 ||
                  "File size shouldn't be more than 1MB!",
                acceptedFormats: (file) =>
                  ["image/png", "image/jpeg"].includes(file[0]?.type) ||
                  "Only JPEG and PNG files are accepted!",
              },
            }}
            render={({ field: { value, onChange, ...field } }) => {
              return (
                <input
                  {...field}
                  value={value?.fileName}
                  onChange={(event) => {
                    onChange(event.target.files[0]);
                  }}
                  type="file"
                  id="photograph"
                />
              );
              
            }}
          />
```

```
      <p>{errors.photograph?.message}</p>
```

#### The validate errors appear even when the file size is just 10kb and uploaded file is a png or jpeg.

Comment: Are you sure ```file``` is an array? You are calling ```onChange(event.target.files[0])``` and then accessing it again as array ```file[0]?.size```. Isn't it just ```file?.size``` ?

Comment: Thanks. That fixed the problem completely!